# ORACLE 12c ins-10008 Can't install software

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I can't install Oracle software on my computer - 
does anyone have problem like that ?

[image: error]

Comment: So have you had a look in the log? What do they have?

Comment: where i can find the log ??

Comment: If you're going to use Oracle you should learn to use the documentation: it's comprehensive, online and free. [Find it here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/ts.htm#NTDBI2934)

Comment: WARNING: Error reading registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ORACLE\ALL_HOMES\ID0\NAME
INFO: 
Query Exception: ErrorReadingWindowsRegistry
Query Exception Class: class oracle.sysman.oii.oiil.OiilQueryException
SEVERE: [FATAL] An error occurred while reading the registry..
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.commons.util.exception.AbstractErrorAdvisor:3968
INFO: Advice is ABORT
SEVERE: Unconditional Exit
INFO: Adding ExitStatus FAILURE to the exit status set
INFO: Adding ExitStatus SUCCESS_WITH_WARNINGS to the exit

Comment: So that says there's a stack trace. Is there? Have you read it?